# Vb.net timer not working like I want

Tags: vb.net

I have a timer in my program, the timer triggers a progress bar and when the progress bar is done it makes a label visible. The problem is that the label becomes visible before the progress bar finishes. here is my code.

```
 Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "Microsoft Office" Then
        ProgressBar1.Visible = True
        ProgressBar1.Increment(5)
    End If
    If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "Windows 8" Then
        ProgressBar1.Visible = True
        ProgressBar1.Increment(1)
    End If
    If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "Sony Vegas Pro 12.0" Then
        ProgressBar1.Visible = True
        ProgressBar1.Increment(10)
    End If
    If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "Minecraft Premium" Then
        ProgressBar1.Visible = True
        ProgressBar1.Increment(20)
    End If
    If ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
        Timer1.Stop()
        ProgressBar1.Value = 0
        ProgressBar1.Visible = False
        Button1.Visible = False
        Button2.Visible = True
    End If
    If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "Microsoft Office" Then
        Label4.Visible = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "Windows 8" Then
        Label5.Visible = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "Sony Vegas Pro 12.0" Then
        Label6.Visible = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "Minecraft Premium" Then
        Label7.Visible = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

If I could get answer on why the label appears before the progress bar becomes visible that would be great!

Comment: WHICH label? You several being set based solely on a combo box selection and **not** whether the progessbar is done.  BTW the combobox selection could change between ticks and maybe look like a bug depending what this does

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in the logic of your `If` statements.  The last three that make one of the `Label`s visible are evaluated and executed on each tick.  If you only want them to be evaluated when the progress bar is done, try it more like this:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "Microsoft Office" Then
        ProgressBar1.Visible = True
        ProgressBar1.Increment(5)
    End If
    If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "Windows 8" Then
        ProgressBar1.Visible = True
        ProgressBar1.Increment(1)
    End If
    If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "Sony Vegas Pro 12.0" Then
        ProgressBar1.Visible = True
        ProgressBar1.Increment(10)
    End If
    If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "Minecraft Premium" Then
        ProgressBar1.Visible = True
        ProgressBar1.Increment(20)
    End If
    If ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Maximum Then
        Timer1.Stop()
        ProgressBar1.Value = 0
        ProgressBar1.Visible = False
        Button1.Visible = False
        Button2.Visible = True

        If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "Microsoft Office" Then
            Label4.Visible = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "Windows 8" Then
            Label5.Visible = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "Sony Vegas Pro 12.0" Then
            Label6.Visible = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
        If ComboBox1.SelectedItem = "Minecraft Premium" Then
            Label7.Visible = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: what is the difference between my code and the one you have provided?

Comment: The `End If` from the line `If ProgressBar1.Value = ProgressBar1.Maximum Then` has been moved to after the three `If` statements that set the label visibility, ensuring they're run only when the progress bar has reached its end.  It's important to remember that the execution of one `If` statement doesn't prevent anything else that comes after it from happening unless those other statements are contained in an alternative block (an `Else` or `ElseIf` block, for example).